# Youtube leanback on PS3

Tags: ps3

Is there any way to use Youtube leanback on PS3?

I tried but the Youtube page says it doesn't support, but is there a way to workaround it?

For example changing the UAString of PS3?

Answer (score 1):

[YouTube XL](http://www.youtube.com/xl) is a similar experience and [does work on the ps3](http://technologizer.com/2011/02/18/youtube-for-game-consoles-sounds-good/). I imagine if YouTube is blocking "Leanback" on the ps3 they are doing it because it simply doesn't work properly (most likely do to the way the page looks on the PS3's browser). Simply changing the user agent of your browser to "trick" YouTube will most likely just result in a more cryptic error or unusable interface.

Comment: I wanted to use leanback because with it can control youtube using a the youtube remote app for android.

Comment: The only problem with YouTubeXL is it looks terrible on the PS3 with a big telly.